# Why is my method in application_controller not visible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my applicatin_controller.rb I added:

```
def test?
   true
end
```

I tried using it in my view and it didn't work

<%= test? %>

error:

```
undefined method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller methods are not accessible in the view by default.
Try the following:

```
def test?
  true
end
helper_method :test?
```

Comment: You missed a `?` mate :D `:test?` instead.

Comment: I addeD helper :all, will that work in theory?  b/c it isn't for me!

Comment: helper :all is entirely different. It makes all of the helpers/*_helper.rb files available to all views.